# how to achieve explicit time out and implicit time out in protractor using typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor

while selecting elements by using xpath and while page is getting reload. it is showing TIMEOUT Error. 
with use of browser.sleep(5000 i.e some value) i can make run the test case with out error. But how to make it applicable for every element when even is needed instead of writing everytime browser.sleep

Answer (score 0):

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  print: function() {},
  showColors: true,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000,
}
```

the above conf helps you to solve your issue

for implicit always use the protractor `ExcpectedConditions(EC)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `browser.sleep` use `browser.wait`

Example:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be visible on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#abc')), 5000);
```

For more details check https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers!

Implicit Wait : To wait for certain time, we can use browser.sleep()

```
browser.sleep(3000) //waits for 3 seconds
```

Explicit Wait : You can achieve explicit wait with Expected conditions

```
//Will wait till element is visible, if not visible in 5 sec, will timeout     
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('abc')),5000, 'abc element is not visiblie');
```

Another advantage, we can use .then to do required action once the element is visible.

```
//Do something once the element is visible     
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('abc')),5000, 'abc element is not visiblie').then(()=>{
   //code once the element is visible
});
```

Cheers!